# Binding two datasets in R when only some of the rows match

Tags: c#, r, dataset

Basically, I want to bind two datasets in R by the column "country", and in both datasets this column contains a list of every country. One dataset is of GDP-level data, and the other is of internet penetration data. However, the dataset for internet-level data has a more comprehensive list of countries, with some included (such as Andorra) that are not included in the GDP dataset. I want to bind them together, wherein the dataset maintains its more comprehensive list of countries from the internet data, but the GDP data remains blank for those countries.

Using rbind nets the following error:

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
>   numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Using rbind.fill nets a successful bind, but it just combines the two datasets, without binding by country (i.e. it treats "Austria," in the internet dataset and "Austria," in the GDP dataset as separate rows, though the coulmns both named country is combined into one row).

How do you bind two datasets by row when the column you seek to bind them by is not a 1-to-1 match?

Comment: Can you provide example data? See here: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/786542)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest first cleaning your names with

```
library(janitor) clean_names(),
```

then use 
`library(dplyr) bind_rows()` which, in case a column exists in only one data frame, it will still appear